# Testing on iOS 5 and iOS 6. How can I do it?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, safari

How can you test web apps that you have created on Safari found in iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Will I have to downgrade an iOS device or use the Xcode simulator?

Comment: The simulator will work since the simulator has Mobile Safari. But using real devices with the proper version of iOS is always better since the simulator isn't perfect.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes. Do you know how to obtain the proper version of iOS on a device? How am I able to downgrade 2 versions for instance...

Comment: Do a Google search. There are countless hits on how to downgrade an iOS device.